Quasi-coherent subsheaf of a coherent sheaf is coherent
I do not know what a scheme is, and I define quasi coherent in terms of exact sequences locally, not $\hat{M}$.
I am reading Kempf Sheaf Theory, and this is given as exercise 5.3.2.
I say a sheaf of $R$-modules $M$ on a top. space $X$ is quasicoherent if $\forall x\in X$ there an open neighbourhood $U$ and an exact sequence of sheaves
$$ R^I|_U\to R^J|_U \to M|_U \to 0$$
for some (infinite) sets $I,J$. If we can always choose $U,I,J$ such that $I,J$ are finite, we say $M$ is coherent. Note that I use $R^I$ to denote the direct sum.
The exercise is

Prove that a quasi-coherent $O_X$-module on a variety $X$
which is contained in a coherent one is also coherent

Inspired by this question, which uses a different (equivalent) definition of quasicoherent I don't want to use. I attempt to prove the stronger claim:

Let $R$ be a sheaf of Noetherian rings and $     M$ and $ N$ sheaves of $ R$-modules with $ M \subset      N$. If $ N$ is coherent and $ M$ is quasi-coherent, then     in fact $ M$ is coherent.

Let $x\in X$. Then there is an open neighbourhood $U$ with exact sequences of sheaves
\begin{align}
    &{R}^p|_U \to {R}^q|_U \to {N}|_U \to 0 \\
    &{R}^I|_U \to {R}^J|_U \to {M}|_U \to 0 
\end{align}
for some integers $p,q$ and sets $I$ and $J$.Thus, for every $y\in U$ there is an exact sequence of $ R(U)$-modules
\begin{align}
     &({R}^I|_U)_y \to ({R}^J|_U)_y \to ({M}|_U)_y \to 0 
\end{align}
Thus $( M|_U)_y$ is finitely generated as it is a submodule of $( N|_U)_y$ (using $R$ Noetherian). It is also finitely presented. Lets say the number of generators is $d$ and presentations is $e$
$e$ and $d$ are functions of $y$, but we need a uniform choice of $d$ and $e$ that works on all of some open neighbourhood of $x$. How do we do that?
EDIT:
$(N|_U)_y$ is generated by $q$ elements, by the first exact sequence. Thus $(N|_U)_y$ is a quotient of $R(U)^q$. So $(M|_U)_y$ is a quotient of a submodule of $R(U)^q$. Thus $(M|_U)_y)$ is generated by at most $q$ elements. So $d\le q$.

Why are you taking stalks? You just need to show $I$ and $J$ can be chosen to be finite, which you already know how to do

@Exitpath I'm not taking stalks, im just using the definition of an exact sequence of sheaves.

Why are you choosing a point $y$?

@Exitpath I need an $R(U)$-module to use my hypotheses. The only other $R(U)$-module I can think of is $M(U)$ but we don't know anything about it.

I see. Are you sure the result holds for general ringed spaces? You say you don’t know what schemes are, so I assume you are working in greater generality

@Exitpath No I am not sure. The statement in the book I am reading is "Prove that a quasi-coherent $O_X$-module on a variety $X$ which is contained in a coherent one is also coherent". Based on the question I linked, I presumed "Noetherian" was the important part.

A variety is a special case of a scheme, and the proof is the same as the linked question. The important thing about schemes is they are locally rings, and thus quasicoherent sheaves have a convenient description: locally they are given by modules over the relevant ring

@Exitpath I am looking for the details of the linked proof, ideally using my definition of quasi-coherent, not their definition using $\hat M$.

Again, you seem to be asking for a proof which does not use the fact that your space is a scheme. I’m not convinced this is possible (though I don’t know). Their definition is equivalent to yours for schemes

@Exitpath I think we can say $d\le q$ since $rank((M|_U)_y)\le rank((N|_U)_y)\le q$, so this would fix it? Not sure about $p$

You seem to be treating $M$ and $N$ as modules over a ring $R$. This is not generally true - of course, you can make an argument to reduce to this case, but you didn't make it, and given that you've said that you "do not know what a scheme is", I'm suspicious that you understand what's going on here. Can you start from the beginning: how did you get to this problem, are you studying out of a textbook/course/notes (which one[s], if yes?), what background do you know about the situation, and can you define your exact setup explicitly? (For instance, a sheaf is on something - what's that here?)

@KReiser I haven't treated $M$ and $N$ as modules, I am treating the stalks as modules. I'm learning from Kempf Sheaf Theory. The exercise is stated in terms of varieties (ie quasiprojective varieties), and I assumed Noetherianness was the important part when making my question here. The book suggests proving this in terms of the $\hat M$ definition of quasicoherent but I wanted to prove it using the local exact sequences definition.

Great, thanks for the info. There are a few more questions in my comment, and I'd like you to respond to those too. Specifically, what book, what exercise, and what are your definitions? Please place this information in the question with an [edit].

@KReiser No problem
